# Where to define user roles in a spring protlet application?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, websphere-portal, user-roles

In my Spring portlet controller, I have a method annotated like this:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_BankUser')
```

Now when a user logs in to the portal and tries to access the portlet, where from will this method know if the user has a role of 'ROLE_BankUser'? Is it going to be defined in the LDAP where the user has all other credentials(like login and password)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your SpringSecurity configuration. Which **AuthenticationProvider** implementation do you use? In a case of LDAP it may be **LdapAuthenticationProvider**. If it's true then you can check how LdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(Authentication authentication) method is implemented. It will load roles from LDAP via some LdapAuthoritiesPopulator implementation (depends on your configuration)

Comment: We are using AuthenticationUserDetailsService.loadUserDetails method